# The existence of a larger compact set containing all minimising geodesics of a compact subset

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, geodesic

On a hyperbolic surface, is a compact set $K$ necessarily contained in a larger compact set $K’$ so that any two points of $K$ can be joined by a minimising geodesic within $K’$?

The question came out when I was studying the Pick Theorem in the book *Dynamics in One Complex Variable* by John Milnor (Page22).

At the end of the proof, it seems that the answer of my question is obviously yes so that one can choose such a larger compact set $K’$ to conclude the proof. But I am just unsure about the existence of such a larger compact set $K’$.

Here’s my attempt. Let $G$ be the union of all geodesics of $K$, that is, $x$ is in $G$ if and only if $x$ is on a minimising geodesic joining some two points of $K$. If we can prove $G$ to be bounded(I still cannot work this out), then we can take the closed ball containing $G$ as the wanted $K’$.

Any help and discussion will be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of geodesic convexity? (There are two competing notions.)

Comment: @ Moishe Kohan, thank you for pointing this out. I realised I mixed up the concept of geodesic convexity and the statements of the proof in the book. Sorry. Now I’ve re-edit my problem.

Comment: In the new version, the answer is positive and quite easy (your idea works). Incidentally, the claim is also true if you define a subset $C$ to be convex if for every two points of  $C$ there exists a (not necessarily minimizing) geodesic connecting $, y$ and contained in $C$. Then every compact subset is contained in a compact convex subset.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks! And I’ve also worked out the proof of my question. But as for the incidental result: ”every compact subset is contained in a compact convex subset”, I have little idea to show it..

Comment: What is the "incident result?"

Comment: @MoisheKohan  I refer to it as the claim ”Every compact subset is contained in a compact convex subset”. I was wondering: are all metric balls on a hyperbolic surface convex?

Comment: Oh, this result is false (if you define convexity using minimizing geodesics). I will write an example a bit later. I will also add a proof of the positive result if minimization is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two relevant notions of convexity for **complete** Riemannian manifolds $M$:

a. A subset $C\subset M$ is weakly convex if for all pairs of points $x, y\in C$ there exists a geodesic $c$ in $M$ connecting $x, y$, such that $c\subset C$.

b. A subset $C\subset M$ is strongly convex if for all pairs of points $x, y\in C$ there exists a minimizing geodesic $c$ in $M$ connecting $x, y$, such that $c\subset C$.

(The terminology "weakly" and "strongly" convex is mine, as there is no consistent terminology in the literature.)

Lemma 1. Suppose that $M$ is a complete (connected) hyperbolic surface. Then for every compact $K\subset M$ there exists a weakly convex compact subset  $C\subset M$ containing $K$.

Proof. There exists a compact subset $\tilde{K}$ of the hyperbolic plane ${\mathbb H}^2$ (the universal covering space of $M$) which projects onto $K$ under the universal covering map $\pi: {\mathbb H}^2\to M$. Since $\tilde{K}$ is compact, there exists a closed metric ball $B\subset {\mathbb H}^2$ containing $\tilde{K}$. Then $C=\pi(B)$ contains $K$. Let us check that $C$ is weakly  convex. Take any pair of points $x, y\in C$. Since $\pi(B)=C$, there are points $p, q\in B$ such that $\pi(p)=x, \pi(q)=y$. Since $B$ is convex, the hyperbolic geodesic $pq$ connecting $p, q$, is contained in $B$. Thus, $\pi(pq)$ is a geodesic in $M$ connecting $x, y$ and contained in $C$. (To be more precise, one should work with geodesic paths rather than images of geodesics.) Hence, $C$ is weakly convex. qed

Lemma 2. There are complete hyperbolic surfaces $M$ and compacts $K\subset M$ such that $K$ is not contained in any strongly convex compact subset of $M$.

Proof. Let $M$ be the quotient of the hyperbolic upper half-plane by the cyclic group $\Gamma$ of isometries generated by $z\mapsto z+1$. The group $\Gamma$ preserves the horocycle $H\subset {\mathbb H}^2$ given by the equation $Im(z)=1$. The projection of $H$ to the surface $M$ is a smooth circle $K\subset  M$ (actually, also a horocycle in $M$). The subset $K$ is, of course, compact. Suppose that $C\subset M$ is the smallest closed strongly convex subset containing $K$. Then the preimage $\tilde{C}$ of $C$ in ${\mathbb H}^2$ is also convex. One verifies that $\tilde{C}$ has to be invariant under the group $G$ of all translations $z\mapsto z+t$, $t\in {\mathbb R}$ (since $H$ is $G$-invariant). Thus,    $\tilde{C}$ has to be of the form $U_{b}$,
$$
\{z: 1\le Im(z)\le b\}
$$
or
$$
U=\{z: 1\le Im(z)\}.
$$
In the former case, $U_{b}$ is not convex. In the latter case, $\pi(U)\subset M$ is noncompact. qed